# How to compute an equation if a matrix is singular?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

as homework, I was supposed to find $X$ in this equation:
$AX=B$, where $$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 5 \\ 2 & 4 & 7 \\ 4 & 8 & 9 \end{matrix} \right) $$
and
$$ B = \left( \begin{matrix} 31 & 53 & 22 \\ 50 & 85 & 35 \\ 80 & 135 & 55 \end{matrix} \right) $$
Knowing that $A$ is a singular matrix that is therefore not invertible, I cannot do the ordinary equation $X=A^{-1}B$. This equation would not have a solution if $B$ had a determinant that was different from 0. But $B$ is also a singular matrix, so there is a possibility of a solution. I know there is a solution, which is
$$ X = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 5 & 8 & 2 \\ 4 & 7 & 3 \end{matrix} \right) $$
but I don't know, how to arrive to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix equation is actually three systems of equations in disguise. Let's denote the columns of $B$ as $\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2, \vec{b}_3$, from left to right. To find such an $X$, we need to find vectors $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2, \vec{x}_3$ where
$$A \vec{x}_1 = \vec{b}_1, ~ A \vec{x}_2 = \vec{b}_2, ~ A \vec{x}_3 = \vec{b}_3$$
because indeed if this is the case, then
$$A \begin{bmatrix} \vec{x}_1 & \vec{x}_2 & \vec{x}_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A\vec{x}_1 & A\vec{x}_2 & A\vec{x}_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{b}_1 & \vec{b}_2 & \vec{b}_3 \end{bmatrix} = B$$
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect, I now understand everything. I think it's also true that one can work with rows instead of columns, and it would still work, right?

Comment: Actually, this way specifically would not work. It's because $A \begin{bmatrix} \vec{r}_1^T \\ \vec{r}_2^T \\ \vec{r}_3^T \end{bmatrix} \neq  \begin{bmatrix} A\vec{r}_1^T \\ A\vec{r}_2^T \\ A\vec{r}_3^T \end{bmatrix}$ in general. The linear transformation $A$ operates on the rows. If instead you were asked to find $X$ such that $X A = B$, then we could do this procedure with the rows (and in fact, not the columns) to obtain a solution $X$ (if it exists).